# Changing highcharts options with buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a kind of complicated first-time project going on and I'm still learning highcharts. I'm using highcharts to show data from a webserver. the user selects what data series he wants to see and it's presented in the chart.

I want to have a couple of checkboxes and drop downs the user can select from to alter how the highchart is presented. Including yAxis 0 and 1's line style. (solid, doted, dashed etc.), weather the series in the chart has points, something along the lines of `Chart.options.line.marker.enabled = true/false`.

I'm having a hard time understanding the API as I'm still new at this.

For example, checking and unchecking for line markers currently looks like this, though it's not working. It returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'marker' of undefined`

```
var chart = $(newDisplay).find('.chartWrapper').highcharts()

$(newDisplay).on('click', '.chkShowLinePoints', function () { //delegate to checkbox
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) { //ON
        chart.options.line.marker.enabled = true

    } else { //OFF
        chart.options.line.marker.enabled = false
    }
})
```

The chart itself is constructed elsewhere and is working fine. I just don't understand how i can change the chart options. Is what you can change after creation limited?

I can add and remove a plotline to mark the current date and time on the chart, but that's because of the `addPlotLine` and `removePlotLine` function in highcharts.  I'm looking for something for the other kind of options

```
.on('click', '.chkMarkCurrentTime', function () {            
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) { //ON
        chart.xAxis[0].addPlotLine({
            color: '#ddd',
            width: 1,
            value: new Date().getTime(),
            id: 'plot-line-1'
        });
    } else { //OFF
        chart.xAxis[0].removePlotLine('plot-line-1');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a broad question and there are multiple API calls I will just point you to the series options changes you can do via [`series\[N\].update()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update). It depends on what you are trying to update. Your issue with the marker on the line not showing is a syntax error:

```
chart.options.line.marker.enabled
```

should become:

```
chart.options.plotOptions.line.marker.enabled
```

I recommend doing a `console.log(chart);` inside your click events so you can see the formatting of the chart object.

Comment: perfect! just the direction i needed.

Answer (score 1):

To change chart dynamically you can use API functions listed in API reference in section "Methods and properties" (starting at: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis)

It is also possible to change chart by changing some chart options manually or using internal, undocumented options, but easier way is usually rebuilding chart with new options.

To get started with Highcharts you might find useful General Documentation: http://www.highcharts.com/docs